# Не выводит список в jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Список MealTo передается правильно и хранит в себе элементы, но  его элементы не выводятся. Геттеры определены.

```xml
<c:forEach items="${mealToList}" var="meal">
  <tr>
    <%-- <% System.out.println(pageContext.findAttribute("mealToList")); %> --%>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${meal.id}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${meal.datetime}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${meal.description}" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <c:out value="${meal.calories}" />
      </td>
      <td><a href="meals?action=edit&userId=<c:out value=" ${meal} "/>">Update</a></td>
      <td><a href="meals?action=delete&userId=<c:out value=" ${meal.id} "/>">Delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Вот содержимое списка MealToList, проверенное внутри jsp

```
DEBUG MealServlet [MealServlet.java:28] redirect to meals
[MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-30T10:00, description='Завтрак', calories=500, excess=false}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-30T13:00, description='Обед', calories=1000, excess=false}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-30T20:00, description='Ужин', calories=500, excess=false}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-31T00:00, description='Еда на граничное значение', calories=100, excess=true}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-31T10:00, description='Завтрак', calories=1000, excess=true}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-31T13:00, description='Обед', calories=500, excess=true}, MealTo{dateTime=2020-01-31T20:00, description='Ужин', calories=410, excess=true}]
```

Comment: А ошибок тоже не выводит? Где `id`, почему вместо `dateTime` `datetime` (все буквы маленькие)?

Comment: Возможно по поводу ошибок мог чего-то не увидеть, но изменение регистра буквы T также не помогло на тот момент

Comment: Судя по всему, первая ошибка - это то, что в данных нет поля `id`. Сначала этот уровень надо пройти, и только потом сыграет буква `T`

Comment: Этого поля нет, но оно генерируется автоматически при создании объекта через сервис

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в `pom.xml` зависимость

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

И импортировал в jsp `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`